# JavaFX desktop app through web start (jnlp) - inconsistent behaviour

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm getting inconsistent behavior when trying to deploy my JavaFX desktop application via Java Web Start, specifically when it decides to download the jars. 
My code is signed.

What is needed:

- Desktop Application that works 100% offline, but checks for updates when there is an internet connection.
- If an update is found, asks the user if he wants to download it. If yes, update and run. If no, run cached version.
- Desktop icons need to be made.

What currently happens that is planned:

- On first run, web start downloads and validates application perfectly.
- Shortcuts are created and in Windows appears under software that can be uninstalled.
- When run from .jnlp file and internet is connected, works perfectly.
- When run from desktop with internet (that was never disconnected), works perfectly.
- When run from desktop shortcut without internet, mostly works perfectly.

What happens that is unplanned:

- When internet is disconnected, application does not work at all if run from .jnlp file. Console indicates that the codebase is not available. According to me it should detect the loss of internet and work from cache, but it does not.
- When run offline (via shortcut which inherently runs the .jnlp file with -offline parameter) at least once, and the internet is connected again and re-launched, web start asks the user to confirm that the software needs to go online now. If the user declines, message indicates that needed files are missing. Program will now never start again unless rerun with internet and indicated that it may go online. What seems like the entire application with all dependencies are then re-downloaded.
- The same happens sometimes even while still offline. Offline shortcut works once and runs software, console then indicates that some jars have been invalidated. When re-launched will then give same problem as above.
- If run for the first time and the software installed and launched, and the internet disconnected quickly after that, and re-launched. Software will not work offline, indicating that not all the resources have been downloaded. Seeing as all the jars are set to download eagerly and checking for updates is set to "timeout", I see no reason for this.

Stranger still is that there seems to be a discrepancy in behavior between Linux and Windows. Although not perfect, it seems to be a lot more consistent on Linux, with offline shortcut never checking for updates. While on windows sometimes it requires re-download which then updates.

If the current deployment wasn't this unpredictable the current logic seems to be that to update the application at all the user needs to run the software from the .jnlp file and not from the shortcut.

Anyway, long description aside, can anybody find something wrong in my .jnlp file, given below? What I really want is for the shortcut to both work online and offline, checking for updates when online but not losing the cached versions of the application when no change is made to the jars - and not re-downloading the software unnecessarily.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- JNLP File for example-->
<jnlp 
    spec="7.0+"  codebase="http://www.example.co.za/downloads/example"
    xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" 
    href="Example.jnlp">
    <information>
            <title>Example</title>
            <vendor>My Company</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.example.co.za/products" />
            <description>Example is an example application</description>
        <icon href="../shared/example_icon.png"/> 
            <icon kind="splash" href="../shared/example_splash.png" />
        <icon kind="shortcut" href="../shared/example_icon.png" />
        <shortcut online="false" install="true"> 
            <desktop/>
            <menu submenu="My Company"/>
        </shortcut>     
    <offline-allowed/>  </information> <security>  <all-permissions/> </security> <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="8.0+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
    <update check="timeout" policy="prompt-update"/>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+" java-vm-args="-Xms512m"/>
    <jar href="Example.jar" download="eager"/>
    <jar href="Dependency-1.jar" download="eager"/>
    <jar href="Dependency-2.jar" download="eager"/>
    <jar href="Dependency-3.jar" download="eager"/>
    ...

  </resources> 
<application-desc main-class="ExampleMain">
    <applet-desc  width="1024" height="768" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Example Application" >
            <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="8.0+"/>
    </applet-desc>
    <jfx:javafx-desc  width="1024" height="768" main-class="ExampleMain"  name="Example Application" />     
<application-desc/>

</jnlp>
```

Comment: IDE and compiler is IntelliJ IDEA. Permissions, Main Class and Application Name is also included in jar manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

`<application-desc/>` should be `</application-desc>`

Answer (score 0):

The webstart indeed has lots of problems and unexpected behavior.
I have some webstart applications and while deploying them I realized it's best to leave the update options as default to avoid problems. Looks like the only thing that you have different than my jnlp is that you request an update prompt whereas I let it automatically update. Try removing the  tag to let it use the defaults and see if that fixes the problems or at least improve it.

If you like you can try my webstart jnlp to see if my version of jnlp behaves well in your computer:

http://www.runiter.com/graphing-calculator/online.htm

One more thing: the fact that it doesn't run the program when you double click on jnlp without internet connection is normal. When you run the jnlp it needs internet. Only the shortcut can run in offline mode.

Comment: The graphing calculator seems to longer be deployed via Webstart, so no JNLP.

Comment: Yes we decided to opt for downloadable exe instead because webstart solution wasn't reliable. If you like to see the code of our old webstart configuration it's still accessible here (although its signature has expired): http://www.runiter.com/webstart/gc3/grapher.jnlp